# How do I lock drive encrypted by BitLocker but unlocked?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, bitlocker

I have used BitLocker to encrypt main Windows 10 disk.  After successful encryption it appears that mentioned disk is unlocked therefore accessible by anybody (padlock is opened), looking like this:

[image: disk is unlocked (padlock is opened)]
                 <sup>[[Image source]](https://superuser.com/q/1140054/354511)</sup>

I can see no option (e.g., in any drop down menu) to lock it. 
The question is, how do I lock that disk,
preventing anybody unauthorized from accessing it?

Comment: Do you want an encrypted drive that cannot be locked? Please re-read your question very carefully and then use the EDIT button to rewrite it to be more clear. It is difficult to understand what you're actually asking for. One way to make things more clear may be to describe what you want the end result to be, or describe WHY you want the system to behave this way.

Comment: @music2myear: I agree that the question is poor, but I don’t understand where your comment is coming from.   Even from the first revision of the question, it seems fairly clear that the OP ***has*** “an encrypted drive that cannot be locked” and *wants* to be able to lock it.

Comment: tom: You say “it appears that mentioned disk is unlocked therefore accessible by anybody”.  What have you done to verify that the disk is, in fact, accessible by anybody?  Maybe Explorer is just displaying the wrong icon. When did you encrypt the drive?  Just today (or yesterday), or a long time ago?  If you encrypted it a long time ago, has it always been like this, or did it just recently go bad?  If it just recently went bad, what else happened in the system?  (Windows Update?) Have you searched BitLocker documentation?  What does it say? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actively lock your system drive because it would become inaccessible by running processes. If you shutdown your system and move your disk to a different system it will be locked.